# Как вызвать метод несколько раз?

Tags: python, prettytable

Есть код получения инф-ы из базы данных **MySQL**. Инф-а приходит в виде словарей в списке `([{}, {}, {}]).` Нужно преобразовать всё это в таблицу, название полей я вывожу, а вот со значениями траблы. Код:

```
import pymysql
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def viewAll(table):
        connection.ping() # reconnecting mysql
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = (f"SELECT * FROM `{table}`")
            sql_describe = (f"DESCRIBE `{table}`")

            table = PrettyTable()

            field_names = []
            values_list = []

            cursor.execute(sql_describe)

            fields = cursor.fetchall() 
            for field in fields:
                field_names.append(field['Field'])

            table.field_names = [field_name for field_name in field_names]

            cursor.execute(sql)
            values = cursor.fetchall()


            for row in values:
                for i in row.values():
                    values_list.append(i)

            table.add_row([x for x in values_list]) # выводит абсолютно все значения, а так не надо :(


            

            print(table)
            print(field_names, '\n', values_list)
```

Нужно чтобы метод `add_rows` вызывался столько раз, сколько значений в таблице и **генератором списков** выводил строки. Как это реализовать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, попробуйте так:

```
values = cursor.fetchall()

for row in values:
    table.add_row(row.values())

print(table)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Спасли меня!

Comment: по-моему переменная `values` здесь лишняя - `for row in cursor.fetchall():` :)